# Intersection of two Counters

Tags: python, counter, intersection

I'm trying to find the shared elements (and the shared number of occurrences) between two lists. For example, the intersection of these two lists:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
b = [1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

should return `Counter({1: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1})` or something similar, e.g. `{1: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1}` or `[1, 1, 3, 5, 7]` (order of the list doesn't matter).

I already have an approach that works:

```
cnts_a = Counter(a)
cnts_b = Counter(b)
cnts_a_b = Counter()  # counter for the shared values
for key in set(cnts_a).intersection(cnts_b):
    cnts_a_b[key] = min(cnts_a[key], cnts_b[key])
```

But perhaps there is an easier (or faster) way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `&` for intersection:

```
>>> Counter(a) & Counter(b)
Counter({1: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1})
```

[From docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> Intersection(`&`) and union(`|`) return the **minimum** and **maximum** of corresponding counts.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
cnts_a_b = Counter()  # counter for the shared values
for key in set(cnts_a).intersection(cnts_b):
    cnts_a_b[key] = min(cnts_a[k], cnts_b[k])
```

use

```
cnts_a_b = cnts_a & cnts_b
```

as `&` means the *intersection* of the `Counter` objects.