# Frequency of ngrams (strings) in tokenized text

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, nltk, n-gram

I have a set of unique ngrams (list called ngramlist) and ngram tokenized text (list called ngrams). I want to construct a new vector, freqlist, where each element of freqlist is the fraction of ngrams that is equal to that element of ngramlist. I wrote the following code that gives the correct output, but I wonder if there is a way to optimize it:

```
freqlist = [
    sum(int(ngram == ngram_condidate)
        for ngram_condidate in ngrams) / len(ngrams)
    for ngram in ngramlist
]
```

I imagine there is a function in nltk or elsewhere that does this faster but I am not sure which one.

Thanks!

Edit: for what it's worth the ngrams are producted as joined output of [nltk.util.ngrams](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.util.ngrams) and `ngramlist` is just a list made from set of all found ngrams.

Edit2:

Here is reproducible code to test the freqlist line (the rest of the code is not really what I care about)

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
import wikipedia
import nltk
import pandas as pd

articles = ['New York City','Moscow','Beijing']
tokenizer  = nltk.tokenize.TreebankWordTokenizer()

data={'article':[],'treebank_tokenizer':[]}
for article in articles:
    data['article' ].append(wikipedia.page(article).content)
    data['treebank_tokenizer'].append(tokenizer.tokenize(data['article'][-1]))

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df['ngrams-3']=df['treebank_tokenizer'].map(
    lambda x: [' '.join(t) for t in ngrams(x,3)])

ngramlist = list(set([trigram for sublist in df['ngrams-3'].tolist() for trigram in sublist]))

df['freqlist']=df['ngrams-3'].map(lambda ngrams_: [sum(int(ngram==ngram_condidate) for ngram_condidate in ngrams_)/len(ngrams_) for ngram in ngramlist])
```

Comment: Where did you get the function from? What is in the input `ngramlist`? What is the expected output?

Comment: What's the code before the line you've posted?

Comment: made an edit with the code to generate

Comment: @alvas. What does it really matter?

Comment: @Ilya. Unfortunately, the code you showed does not really help us reproduce your actual data, so there is no purpose to it in the question. Fortunately though, I don't thing you really need it in the first place.

Comment: @Mad Physicist I've updated the code for a fully reproducible version (didn't do this before since I was using a different dataset that I couldn't share, but now just use wikipedia instead). I am pretty sure there is a faster way to make the df['freqlist'] and I want to find the way. Anyways, I will continue googling and post the answer when I find it. Edit: The current approach I am using is excruciatingly slow and it is all in that one line.

Comment: I'm almost done with an answer.

Comment: It's because initially, you're doing some weird things like using `ngrams` in your import namespace and using `len(ngrams)` like it's  a variable.

Comment: Your last line of code is `O(mn)` where m is the no. of features in `ngramlist` and n is the no. of rows you have. You need to do some proper vectorization.

Comment: @alvas the namespace is not a problem (since it's ngrams vs ngrams_) just in the original line i removed the _ to avoid confusion. if you look at the reproducible code there is no collision. I know my last line is O(m n), I am wondering how to improve it.

Comment: Yes, the namespace IS a problem. Writing clear code helps you think about the problem better and explains the question better. BTW, writing an answer to answer all the rest of your code (it's a little problematic) =)

Comment: @alvas Ok thanks. The rest of the code is kind of thrown last minute to try to make a reproducible snippet but I am curious to hear what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably optimize this a bit by pre-computing some quantities and using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). This will be especially useful if most of the elements in `ngramlist` are contained in `ngrams`.

```
freqlist = [
    sum(int(ngram == ngram_candidate)
            for ngram_candidate in ngrams) / len(ngrams)
        for ngram in ngramlist
]
```

You certainly don't need to iterate over `ngrams` every single time you check an `ngram`. One pass over `ngrams` will make this algorighm `O(n)` instead of the `O(n2)` one you have now. Remember, shorter code is not necessarily better or more efficient code:

```
from collections import Counter
...

counter = Counter(ngrams)
size = len(ngrams)
freqlist = [counter.get(ngram, 0) / size for ngram in ngramlist]
```

To use this function properly, you would have to write a `def` function instead of a `lambda`:

```
def count_ngrams(ngrams):
    counter = Counter(ngrams)
    size = len(ngrams)
    freqlist = [counter.get(ngram, 0) / size for ngram in ngramlist]
    return freqlist
df['freqlist'] = df['ngrams-3'].map(count_ngrams)
```

Comment: I didn't think about the counter.get(). I like this solution, thanks!

Comment: BTW, don't use `ngrams` as a variable. It's a function imported in the namespace =)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't pollute your imported functions by overriding them and using them as variables, keep the `ngrams` name as the function, and use something else as variable.

```
import time
from functools import partial
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

import wikipedia

import pandas as pd

from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams
```

Next the steps before the line you're asking in the original question might be a little inefficient, you can clean them up, make them easier to read and measure them as such:

```
# Downloading the articles.
titles = ['New York City','Moscow','Beijing']
start = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame({'article':[wikipedia.page(title).content for title in titles]})
end = time.time()
print('Downloading wikipedia articles took', end-start, 'seconds')
```

And then:

```
# Tokenizing the articles
start = time.time()
df['tokens'] = df['article'].apply(word_tokenize)
end = time.time()
print('Tokenizing articles took', end-start, 'seconds')
```

Then:

```
# Extracting trigrams.
trigrams = partial(ngrams, n=3)
start = time.time()
# There's no need to flatten them to strings, you could just use list()
df['trigrams'] = df['tokens'].apply(lambda x: list(trigrams(x)))
end = time.time()
print('Extracting trigrams took', end-start, 'seconds')
```

Finally, to the last line

```
# Instead of a set, we use a Counter here because 
# we can use an intersection between Counter objects later.
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012479/intersection-of-two-counters
all_trigrams = Counter(chain(*df['trigrams']))

# More often than not, you don't need to keep all the 
# zeros in the vectors (aka dense vector), 
# you could actually get the non-zero sparse vectors 
# as a dict as such
df['trigrams_count'] = df['trigrams'].apply(lambda x: Counter(x) & all_trigrams)

# Now to normalize the count, simply do:
def featurize(list_of_ngrams):
    nonzero_features = Counter(list_of_ngrams) & all_trigrams
    total = len(list_of_ngrams)
    return {ng:count/total for ng, count in nonzero_features.items()}

df['trigrams_count_normalize'] = df['trigrams'].apply(featurize)
```

Comment: This addresses all the issues I left out. Very nice.

Comment: Thank you for the post. 1. yeah, the downloading articles thing I agree with, not sure why I wrote it the way I did, just wanted to output a snippet as fast as I could since people asked for it. 

2. partial trigrams line actually doesn't do what the original line does since you need to do a ' '.join() on the tuple (because the real underlying code actually does something with the ngram strings). I guess I can use a lambda though.

3. The use of counter instead of list of set is interesting, are we guaranteed that the order is preserved for every application?

Comment: If you're using ngram strings to do something and then vectorize, then you're doing it inefficiently. What truly matters at the end is the vector values (dense/sparse), the feature (key) itself, the machine learning algorithm don't really care as long as it's consistent.

Comment: @alvas I basically find intersects between sets of ngrams. As far as I know you can't do an intersect between two sets of sets (is that correct?), so I join() so I can compute intersects between sets of strings. To clarify, I have several labels and I want to only consider ngrams that occur in both label classes a sufficient amount of times.

Comment: Yes, you can do intersection between sets =) And in fact the Pythonic syntax very "humanly-readable" `set(x).intersection(set(y))`

Comment: I understand the line above, this is what I do where x is a set of ngrams for label = 0 and y is a set of ngrams for label = 1. But I was under impression that x and y cannot be a set of sets (which is why I simply made each ngram set into a string with join).

Comment: IMHO, don't trust strings, strings are higher-level construct, trust arrays. Strings is supposed to be an array of chars ;P

Comment: Ok, my bad. ngrams are tuples anyways which are hashable. set of sets are unhashable though, but I actually care about order so tuples are fine.

Comment: Hope the answer helps.

Comment: @Ilya. A frozenset is quite hashable if that helps (for the same reason that a tuple is while list is not).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, any immutable containers should be hashable ;P List and set isn't because they're mutable. Basic types (non-containers) are treated differently with regards to mutability and hashability.

Comment: @alvas, ok so doing some timing I think the original snipper + mad physicist final line is about 1 second faster than your code. Part of the problem of testing this is that the download speed actually varies quite a bit (3 to 4 s) but I think on average both download snippets take same time to execute.

Comment: Don't time the whole code. Benchmark each component.

Comment: And BTW, you don't need the intermediate step of `df['trigrams_count'] = ...` if you only need the normalized version =)